# Open HTML5 date picker inside input box click

Tags: javascript, jquery, angular, date, datepicker

I'm trying to open a HTML5 date picker on click inside an input text box using the below code, but it is not working as expected.

However, clicking on the calendar icon does open the date picker (by default). This is inside my Angular 7 application.

Fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/mailmrmanoj/rL1ecp9w/5/

HTML:

```html
<input
  type="date"
  name="startDate"
  id="datePick"
  (click)="openDP()"
  class="input--small"
/>
```

Typescript:

```js
declare var $;

openDP() {           
  $('#datePick').datepicker('show');
}
```

Is there anything wrong with my code?

Reference for the date picker: https://www.w3schools.com/html/tryit.asp?filename=tryhtml_input_date

Comment: Its work fine for me.

Comment: @AlwaysHelping Pls check this fiddle that I've created https://jsfiddle.net/mailmrmanoj/rL1ecp9w/5/

Comment: @forgottofly in your jsfiddle, when i click on input box or icon only alert is pop up, not opening any date picker? is this your problem? or else?

Comment: Yes.. You can remove the alert function and try clicking inside the text box which should open the datepicker.But it's not opening..

Comment: @forgottofly https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ivy-nexqse?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.css Does this solve your problem

Comment: @GaurangDhorda Yes it's solving the problem but creating another where I'm not able to type in the date using keyboard. Pls let me know if any fix for this..Thanks

Comment: @forgottofly as of now if you want to support typing you can click on dd on input, and if you want to open date picker your can click on after dd part. check out in above stackblitz link.. i have not found any other solution of this.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/217343/discussion-between-forgottofly-and-gaurangdhorda).

Answer (score 0):

Try with input `type="text"` instead of `type="date"` and on focus event call function "openDP".

```html
<input name="date" type="text" (focus)="focusFunction()" (focusout)="focusOutFunction()">
```

**Note:**  You can also use angularjs-datepicker instead of default HTML5 date picker as `type="date"` is not supported in Safari or Internet Explorer 11 (or earlier).

Comment: Actually I wanted to use input type= "date" as that's the date defined by UX team