# Keyboard typing inside html 5 date picker not enabling after css override

Tags: javascript, html, css, date, datepicker

I was facing issue with one of the HTML5 date picker wherein I wanted to open it on click inside input text box - [Open HTML5 date picker inside input box click](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62749795/open-html5-date-picker-inside-input-box-click)

For which one of the user had suggested a fix [here](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ivy-nexqse?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.css) but wanted to keep the existing functionality of the HTML5 date picker where I can also type in the date using keyboard.

Please find the css that was used to override the date picker. Any leads on enabling keyboard typing for the existing picker..

I tried doing this `<input type="date" onkeydown="return true" />` but didn't work.

```css
    input[type="date"] {
        position: relative;
    }
    
    /* create a new arrow, because we are going to mess up the native one
    see "List of symbols" below if you want another, you could also try to add a font-awesome icon.. */
    input[type="date"]:after {
        content: "\25BC"; 
        color: #555;
        padding: 0 10px;
    }
    
    /* change color of symbol on hover */
    input[type="date"]:hover:after {
        color: #bf1400;
    }
    
    /* make the native arrow invisible and stretch it over the whole field so you can click anywhere in the input field to trigger the native datepicker*/
    
    input[type="date"]::-webkit-calendar-picker-indicator {
        position: absolute;
        top: 0;
        left: 0px;
        right: 0;
        bottom: 0;
        width: auto;
        height: auto;
        color: transparent;
        background: transparent;
    }
    
    /* adjust increase/decrease button */
    input[type="date"]::-webkit-inner-spin-button {
        z-index: 1;
    }
    
     /* adjust clear button */
     input[type="date"]::-webkit-clear-button {
         z-index: 1;
     }
```

Comment: I think, Both `opened Date-Picker-Dialog` with `typing` is not possible with native html5 input type='date'. Because, When date-picker is opened is treated as a normal dialog, and like any dialog when you click outside it will close dialog. SO its better when you want to type then type in input box, and if user want to pick date from dialog they can click on picker icon.. thats my thought.

Answer (score 1):

If you mean something like this **[DEMO IS HERE](https://codepen.io/rudesoul/pen/qBbQyQO).**

**HTML:**

```
<input type="text" name="startDate" id="datePick" class="input--small"  onkeydown="myFunc()" />
```

**CSS:**

```
input[type="date"] {
    position: relative;
}

input[type="date"]:after {
    content: "\25BC"; 
    color: #555;
    padding: 0 10px;
}

/* change color of symbol on hover */input[type="date"]:hover:after {
    color: #bf1400;
}


input[type="date"]::-webkit-calendar-picker-indicator {
    position: absolute;
    top: 10px;
    left: 0px;
    right: 0;
    bottom: 0;
    width: auto;
    height: auto;
    color: transparent;
    background: transparent;
}

input[type="date"]::-webkit-inner-spin-button {
    z-index: 1;
}

 input[type="date"]::-webkit-clear-button {
     z-index: 1;
 }
```

**JS:**

```
function myFunc(){
document.getElementById('datePick').type = 'date';
  
}
```

Comment: For the first time on mouse click inside calendar it's not opening.